# How to Call Python file in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am new to Angular, Is their any way to call sample Python script in Angular from(.ts) file on click on button? if yes please help me with some blogs

Thanks.

Comment: Client side python, or server side? 

Server side, setup an API to run the script, client side, even if you hack something together don't do it...

Answer (score 3):

Angular (TypeScript) is Client side application, which does not allow to run server side programming language like C#, Python. but alternate you should use Express Fast, unopinionated, minimalist web framework for Node.js along with Angular Application.
you just need to run following scripts.

```
npm install express --save
```

Then your following code

```
// import express JS module into app 
// and creates its variable. 
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express(); 
  
// Creates a server which runs on port 3000 and  
// can be accessed through localhost:3000 
app.listen(3000, function() { 
    console.log('server running on port 3000'); 
} ) 
  
// Function callName() is executed whenever  
// url is of the form localhost:3000/name 
app.get('/name', callName); 
  
function callName(req, res) { 
      
    // Use child_process.spawn method from  
    // child_process module and assign it 
    // to variable spawn 
    var spawn = require("child_process").spawn; 
      
    // Parameters passed in spawn - 
    // 1. type_of_script 
    // 2. list containing Path of the script 
    //    and arguments for the script  
      
    // E.g : http://localhost:3000/name?firstname=Mike&lastname=Will 
    // so, first name = Mike and last name = Will 
    var process = spawn('python',["./hello.py", 
                            req.query.firstname, 
                            req.query.lastname] ); 
  
    // Takes stdout data from script which executed 
    // with arguments and send this data to res object 
    process.stdout.on('data', function(data) { 
        res.send(data.toString()); 
    } ) 
} 
  
// save code as start.js
```

After you call API from Angular httpClient service.